# Tokenize a string using stringstream starting from a specified position or label

Tags: c++, string, parsing, stringstream

I'm working on a parser to parse a mesh file (that has been converted to a string) to make a simple 2D graphic.  Here is an example of how the file is formatted (there are multiple meshes like this that make up the file):

```
# left ladder pole
begin_mesh
dimension   2 2
begin_vertices
-0.3  0.85
-0.2  0.85
-0.3 -0.85
-0.2 -0.85
end_vertices
end_mesh
```

The '#' indicates the beginning of a comment line, and you can see the begin_mesh and begin_vertices keywords that show the beginning of the x and y values.

So basically I want to parse and tokenize the vertices x and y values (the numbers) between the whitespaces between 'begin_vertices' and 'end_vertices'.  Is there any way using stringstream (or possibly other string functions) to do this?  I have more experience using the string functions but because the whitespaces and numbers aren't the same lengths I was running into trouble with those.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve, then yes, you can use `istringstream` to read input from a string as you would do from a file. The following program shows how you would go about parsing the input you provided:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct point
{
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    friend istream& operator >> (istream& is, point& p)
    {
        is >> p.x;
        is >> p.y;
        return is;
    }
};

template<typename InputStream>
void parse_vertices(InputStream& is, vector<point>& v)
{
    point p;
    while (is >> p)
    {
        v.push_back(p);
    }
}
```

The above function is generic, meaning it works equally well with a string stream or with a file stream. Supposing you want to read your input from a string, this is how you would invoke it:

```
int main()
{
    string s =
        R"(-0.3  0.85
        -0.2  0.85
        -0.3 -0.85
        -0.2 -0.85
        )";

    istringstream is(s);

    vector<point> vertices;
    parse_vertices(is, vertices);

    for (point const& p : vertices)
    {
        cout << p.x << " " << p.y << endl;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.